# Concatenate an each loop inside another

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation, each

I want to to concatenate the results of a jquery `each` loop inside of another but am not getting the results I expect.

```
$.each(data, function () {
            counter++;
            var i = 0;
            var singlebar;
            var that = this;
            tableRow = '<tr>' +
            '<td>' + this.foo + '</td>' + //<---- should terminate this instead
            $.each(this.bar, function(){
                singlebar = '<td>' + that.bar[i].baz + '</td>';
                tableRow += singlebar;
                console.log(singlebar); // outputs "<td>the correct data</td>"
            });
            '</tr>';

            $(tableRow).appendTo('#mainTable > tbody');
});
```

The portion inside the nested `each` does not get added to the string that is returned.

I can `console.log(singlebar)` and get the expected results in the console but I cannot concatenate those results inside the primary `each` loop.

I have also tried:

```
        $.each(this.bar, function(){
            tableRow += '<td>' + that.bar[i].baz + '</td>';
        });
```

Which also does not add the desired content.

How do I iterate over this nested data and add it in the midst of the table that the primary `each` statement is building?

---

**The solution** (thanks to sushanth reddy)

I should not have continued trying to concatenate in such a way. I should have added each section of string to `tableRow` as I created it, not all at once. Something more like:

```
            tableRow = '<tr>' +
            '<td>' + this.foo + '</td>';

            $.each(this.bar, function(){
                singlebar = '<td>' + that.bar[i].baz + '</td>';
                tableRow += singlebar;
            });

            tableRow += '</tr>';
```

Comment: `that.bar[i].baz` ? what's the "desired content"? you should first do some `console.log` debugging

Comment: Can you post a real world example at jsfiddle of what you're trying to do? I don't get `this.bar` or `this.foo` it just doesn't make sense in this context. Where are those defined?

Comment: You have `tableRow + singlebar;` instead of `tableRow += singlebar;`

Comment: @Karoly Horvath - I do `console.log` it. I mentioned that above in my text but left it out of the code example. I'll add it in for clarity.

Comment: @elclanrs - the `this` object contains the correct data. I can console log everything and get what I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning at the wrong point.. Try this

```
var counter = 0;
var tableRow = '';
$.each(data, function () {
    counter++;
    var i = 0;
    var singlebar;
    var that = this;
    tableRow = '<tr>' +
    '<td>' + this.foo + '</td>' +
    $.each(this.bar, function(){
        singlebar = '<td>' + that.bar[i].baz + '</td>';
        tableRow += singlebar;
    });
    tableRow +=  '</tr>';

    $(tableRow).appendTo('#mainTable  tbody');
});
```

Check this example [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/S3L22/)

Also make sure you have the table and tbody tags before you append..

Comment: Shoot, sorry. I typed that code in incorrectly. I am actually appending the results as I get through each iteration of the main loop, not returning. I've changed my example... sorry for that.

Comment: I have updated the code.. check the code..  The child selector > was messing it up

Comment: Bingo! Your fiddle helped. The problem was that I was trying to do too much inside the concatenation. By breaking each bit into sections and the `+=` to `tableRow` I was able to get it to work. Thanks so much, sushanth.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $.each(data, function () {
                counter++;
                var i = 0;
                var singlebar;
                var that = this;
                tableRow = '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + this.foo + '</td>';
                $.each(this.bar, function(){
                    singlebar = '<td>' + that.bar[i].baz + '</td>';
                    tableRow = tableRow + singlebar;
                });
                tableRow = tableRow + '</tr>';


    });
return tableRow;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data, function () {
            counter++;
            var i = 0;
            var singlebar;
            var that = this;
            var tableRow = '<tr>' +
            '<td>' + this.foo + '</td>';
            $.each(this.bar, function(){
                singlebar = '<td>' + that.bar[i].baz + '</td>';
                tableRow = tableRow + singlebar;
            });
            tableRow = tableRow + '</tr>';

            return tableRow;
});
```

Comment: uncommented code-only answers are not encouraged, a simple "this should work:" can make an answer look much more professional (;